# How to use ShareLinkTask for both window phone 8 and 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Iam using ShareLinkTask for sharing a url from my WP8 App to social median.Its working for wp8 devices but in case of wp8.1 it doesn't showing social media in sharing option.So i need a solution to work this share option in both  wp8 & wp8.1

iam using the below method:

```
        ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();
        shareLinkTask.Title = "Title";
        shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/", UriKind.Absolute);
        shareLinkTask.Message = "Message";
        shareLinkTask.Show();
```

Comment: Is my answer helpful or not..?

Answer (score 3):

From this [Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/16/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-contracts.aspx#scid:887EC618-8FBE-49a5-A908-2339AF2EC720:6f9bdaa7-a55f-450f-9974-2418aa258603) you have to implement a function in your page which can share.

This is for **windows phone 8.1** :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Register the current page as a share source.
    _dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    _dataTransferManager.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Unregister the current page as a share source.
    _dataTransferManager.DataRequested -= OnDataRequested;
}

protected void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "Some title";
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "Some description"; // Optional 
    e.Request.Data.SetUri(new Uri("http://www.some_uri.com"));
}
```

Comment: How does one open the share task on button click with Windows Phone 8.1 RT?

Comment: I have no idea how this works. I've tried it an nothing happens. It was so easy before, why make it so painful Microsoft. Take something simple and stuff it up